# How to look for heap/stack corruption on HPUX?

Tags: debugging, unix, hp-ux

valgrind isn't available on hpux, otherwise I'd use that. I've compiled on Linux and I'm not getting the same segfault. What tools are available on HPUX for watching for heap/stack corruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the HP supported implementation of GDB + some extra goodies called Wildebeest (WDB) debugger that you can try:

http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?ciid=29080f1bace021100f1bace02110275d6e10RCRD

Comment: That looks promising. Thanks.